# How is a perpetual check reached in this puzzle?

Tags: puzzles, check, perpetual

[This puzzle](https://chesstempo.com/chess-problems/178069) on [chesstempo](https://chesstempo.com/) caught my eye. We play as White:

```
[FEN "4Q/4p1bk/1p1qp2p/p1p1n2B/4P/2P3B1/PP4P/6K b - - 0 1"]

1. Nf3
```

**Side Note:** *The answer is of no importance here, so no spoilers from me. :)*

The puzzle is tagged with [avoiding-perpetual](/questions/tagged/avoiding-perpetual), yet I cannot see the perpetual check here. It has been discussed in the comments under the puzzle:

> - Why not just gxf3 and after Qxg3+, run away with the king to the left board edge and hide between pawns?
> - Because he can’t hide. When the king reaches c2, the black queen attacks from e2. When the king is on b3, the queen moves to b5, and perpetual.

However, I do not think this is quite right. b5 is protected by the White queen.  So, where and how is perpetual reached on this board? I would appreciate a hint instead of the full solution. :)

Comment: I don't think there is a perpetual after gxf3 Qxg3+, but then there doesn't need to be as black is safe then. The perpetual meant is probably in the line Kf2 Ne5 Bxe5 Qd2+, as mentioned in another comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Kf2 is actually the winning move for White and the perpetual results after gxf3.

```
[FEN "4Q/4p1bk/1p1qp2p/p1p1n2B/4P/2P3B1/PP4P/6K b - - 0 1"]

1. Nf3 gxf3 2. Qxg3+
```

Now the White king can not escape the perpetual even though the Black king is very close to checkmate.